# If I follow someone on Twitter, but they don't follow me, can they see my tweets?

Tags: twitter

I follow some people on Twitter who don't follow me.

Can *they* see my tweets, even if they don't follow me?

Answer (score 4):

There are **two** answers to this:

### Public Account

Yes. All they have to do is go to your page `https://twitter.com/yourtwittername` and they can see what you tweet.

### Private Account

No. If they go to your page `https://twitter.com/yourtwittername` all they will see is your name, bio, and link.

If they then try to follow you, you'll get a notification that someone wants to follow you and you'll have to approve the request before they see your tweets.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the access restrictions on your tweets. If your account is public (as is by default), anyone can see your tweets, irrespective of whether they are following you.

Answer (score -1):

No, they can not see your tweets in the news feed.  They can only see your tweet if they go to your page and read down through your tweets.

Comment: This has been already [answered](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/36536/87130), there is no new info in your answer.